# Different result inside train function and outside it

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am playing with tensorflow 2. I did my own model similar to how it is done [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced).

Then I created my own fit function. Now I get the weirdest thing ever. Here is the EXACT copy/paste output from my notebook where I did the tests:

```
def fit(x_train, y_train, learning_rate=0.01, epochs=10, batch_size=100, normal=True, verbose=True, display_freq=100):
    if normal:
        x_train = normalize(x_train)  # TODO: This normalize could be a bit different for each and be bad.

    num_tr_iter = int(len(y_train) / batch_size)  # Number of training iterations in each epoch
    if verbose:
        print("Starting training...")
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Randomly shuffle the training data at the beginning of each epoch
        x_train, y_train = randomize(x_train, y_train)
        for iteration in range(num_tr_iter):
            # Get the batch
            start = iteration * batch_size
            end = (iteration + 1) * batch_size
            x_batch, y_batch = get_next_batch(x_train, y_train, start, end)
            # Run optimization op (backpropagation)
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            if verbose and (epoch * batch_size + iteration) % display_freq == 0:
                current_loss = _apply_loss(y_train, model(x_train, training=True))
                current_acc = evaluate_accuracy(x_train, y_train)
                print("Epoch: {0}/{1}; batch {2}/{3}; loss: {4:.4f}; accuracy: {5:.2f} %"
                      .format(epoch, epochs, iteration, num_tr_iter, current_loss, current_acc*100))
            train_step(x_batch, y_batch, learning_rate)

    current_loss = _apply_loss(y_train, model(x_train, training=True))
    current_acc = evaluate_accuracy(x_train, y_train)
    print("End: loss: {0:.4f}; accuracy: {1:.2f} %".format(current_loss, current_acc*100))

import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True
fit(x_train, y_train)

current_loss = _apply_loss(y_train, model(x_train, training=True))
current_acc = evaluate_accuracy(x_train, y_train)
print("End: loss: {0:.4f}; accuracy: {1:.2f} %".format(current_loss, current_acc*100))
```

This segment outputs:

```
Starting training...
Epoch: 0/10; batch 0/80; loss: 0.9533; accuracy: 59.67 %
Epoch: 1/10; batch 0/80; loss: 0.9386; accuracy: 60.15 %
Epoch: 2/10; batch 0/80; loss: 0.9259; accuracy: 60.50 %
Epoch: 3/10; batch 0/80; loss: 0.9148; accuracy: 61.05 %
Epoch: 4/10; batch 0/80; loss: 0.9051; accuracy: 61.15 %
Epoch: 5/10; batch 0/80; loss: 0.8968; accuracy: 61.35 %
Epoch: 6/10; batch 0/80; loss: 0.8896; accuracy: 61.27 %
Epoch: 7/10; batch 0/80; loss: 0.8833; accuracy: 61.51 %
Epoch: 8/10; batch 0/80; loss: 0.8780; accuracy: 61.52 %
Epoch: 9/10; batch 0/80; loss: 0.8733; accuracy: 61.54 %
End: loss: 0.8733; accuracy: 61.54 %
End: loss: 0.4671; accuracy: 77.08 %
```

Now my question is, how is it that I get a different value on the last 2 lines!? I am doing the same thing right? I am totally puzzled here. I don't even know how to google this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was just stupid. It was due to the normalize thing I did at the start of the train example! Removed it and started working Ok.